# Rails & Postgresql: how to group queries by hour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, time, group-by

How do I group by hour in Postgres & Rails? I've read through quite a few SO answers but I'm getting errors.

This works when grouping by date:

```
Model.group("date(updated_at)").count
```

Then I tried the following for hour but they didn't work:

```
Model.group("hour(updated_at)").count
Model.group("date_format(updated_at, '%H')").count
Model.group("extract(hour from updated_at)").count
```

Once I've found certain hours I need to update, how would I then get the models with those hours? I.e:

```
Model.where("hour(updated_at) = ?", 5)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try the following

```
Model.group("DATE_PART('hour', updated_at)").count
```

**UPDATE:**

How to find records

```
Model.where("DATE_PART('hour', updated_at) = ?", 5)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can you please have a look at my updated question - how do I get the second query to work?

Comment: If database datetime is in UTC, how can we add the desired timezone in this query. Thank you.

Comment: change `5` in the query above to something like `Time.zone.now.utc.hour`.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL presents two ways to extract a part of date/time:

`EXTRACT` is SQL standard function that exists in other SQL based databases.

```
Model.group("EXTRACT(hour FROM created_at)").count
Model.where("EXTRACT(hour FROM created_at) = ?", 5)
```

`date_part` function

```
Model.group("date_part('hour', updated_at)").count
Model.where("date_part('hour', updated_at) = ?", 5)
```

The official [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the date and the hour, you can use date_trunc:

`Model.group("date_trunc('hour', created_at)").count`

And if you want the answers in order:

`Model.order("date_trunc('hour', created_at)").group("date_trunc('hour', created_at)").count`

Yeah it's weird that you can't just do `order(:created_at)` but oh well.