# Rails query data by hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm having difficulty querying data by an hour for the previous day. Using Rails 4 on Postgres.

eg,

```
Table X:

created_at, value

timestamp1    3
timestamp2    5
```

I want to get:

```
 time, value
YYMMDD 00:00   15
YYMMDD 01:00   20
```

basically the sum per hour. I've tried

[Rails & Postgresql: how to group queries by hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182051/rails-postgresql-how-to-group-queries-by-hour)

[Is it possible to group by hour/minute/quarter hour directly in ActiveRecord/Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491650/is-it-possible-to-group-by-hour-minute-quarter-hour-directly-in-activerecord-rai)

but I still cant figure out how to get it to work properly, i get the wrong hour for replies. How would i set my timezone along with this query?

TableX.group("DATE_trunc('hour',created_at)").count

Thanks!

Comment: The link you post above is useful and able to solve your problem. It would be better if you can provide more info about obstacle you are encountering, like codes, error logs, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails & Postgresql: how to group queries by hour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182051/rails-postgresql-how-to-group-queries-by-hour)

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! I get {16.0=>11} when I query for test data, I dont think this is the right timezone. How would I set the timezone?

Comment: as @EasonCaizhenLiu point. The link you post above is useful and able to solve your problem.

Comment: @Зелёный Respectfully, it does not. I would hesitate to post a new question if it did. The answer posted below solves it, but the timezone for the string returns wrongly

Comment: This can be tried out -> [groupdate gem](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is create a query like this one:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hours', created_at), sum(value)
FROM TableX
GROUP BY date_trunc('hours', created_at)
```

This one uses date_trunc instead of suggested date_part, which fits your question better.

Comment: THANK YOU! how would I be able to set the timezone in this query?

Comment: Timezone is a connection-wide session property. Just run SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Rome'; after connecting.

Comment: Thats the SQL side, yes? Im using the Rails ORM though, and setting timezone here might affect the rest of the app. is there no way to query just with the zone alone? this is what i have so far:

TableX.group("DATE_trunc('hour',created_at)").count

Comment: I am not sure it is a good idea to define timezones for individual queries. You should consider setting a global timezone - check on this with other developers.